# pip3 list for various python installations

Tags: python, pip

When running `pip3 list` it shows packages installed for default python3.5, but I want it to show installed packages for another python installation, for example python3.6, which libs are located at `/usr/lib/python3.6`, how I can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to run Python 3.6's pip.

On windows this is:

```
py -3.6 -m pip list
```

on MacOS/Linux I believe it is

```
python3.6 -m pip list
```

but substitute in whatever call you make to get to your Python3.6 interpreter.

Comment: Also: it might be illuminating to run `which pip3`

Comment: @TimSeed sure maybe, but that's tough to tell from this limited question :)

Comment: Agreed, it was your *which pip3*, that prompted my.... python env comment.

Comment: `which pip3` is not enough, you also need `pip3 --version`. Aslo `pip3.6 list` should work.